NTS failing to synchronize
I have an embedded Linux device behind a cellular modem. If I add time.cloudflare.com nts iburst to my chrony courses I never see a successful measurement. However, if I add time.cloudflare.com as a plain NTP server I do see measurements. So NTP UDP traffic is getting through. However, NTP UDP traffic doesn't seem to be making it to my device after an NTS handshake. I've tried with multiple NTS providers and am seeing a similar result.
Here is an example of what I see in chronyc when trying to use NTS:
chronyc> sources -v

  .-- Source mode  '^' = server, '=' = peer, '#' = local clock.
 / .- Source state '*' = current best, '+' = combined, '-' = not combined,
| /             'x' = may be in error, '~' = too variable, '?' = unusable.
||                                                 .- xxxx [ yyyy ] +/- zzzz
||      Reachability register (octal) -.           |  xxxx = adjusted offset,
||      Log2(Polling interval) --.      |          |  yyyy = measured offset,
||                                \     |          |  zzzz = estimated error.
||                                 |    |           \
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^? time.cloudflare.com           0  10     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
chronyc> authdata
Name/IP address             Mode KeyID Type KLen Last Atmp  NAK Cook CLen
=========================================================================
time.cloudflare.com          NTS     1   15  256  864    1    0    0    0

Here is an example of what I see when I do a TCP dump
root@imx6ulevk:~# tcpdump -i eth0 host 162.159.200.123 or host 162.159.200.1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
20:50:23.348926 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [S], seq 1490092302, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 797468111 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
20:50:23.378233 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [S.], seq 2558971470, ack 1490092303, win 65160, options [mss 1390,sackOK,TS val 1913138053 ecr 797468111,nop,wscale 13], length 0
20:50:23.379138 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 1, win 1004, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468141 ecr 1913138053], length 0
20:50:23.410044 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 1:349, ack 1, win 1004, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468173 ecr 1913138053], length 348
20:50:23.453464 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [.], ack 349, win 7, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138121 ecr 797468173], length 0
20:50:23.463370 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [P.], seq 1:167, ack 349, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138121 ecr 797468173], length 166
20:50:23.463458 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [.], seq 167:1545, ack 349, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138122 ecr 797468173], length 1378
20:50:23.464574 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 167, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468227 ecr 1913138121], length 0
20:50:23.465368 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 1545, win 991, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468228 ecr 1913138122], length 0
20:50:23.477273 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 349:355, ack 1545, win 991, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468240 ecr 1913138122], length 6
20:50:23.498218 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [P.], seq 1545:2415, ack 349, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138174 ecr 797468227], length 870
20:50:23.539145 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 2415, win 991, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468302 ecr 1913138174], length 0
20:50:23.539414 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [.], ack 355, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138215 ecr 797468240], length 0
20:50:23.573558 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 355:429, ack 2415, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468336 ecr 1913138215], length 74
20:50:23.605271 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [.], ack 429, win 7, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138280 ecr 797468336], length 0
20:50:23.606016 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 429:467, ack 2415, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468369 ecr 1913138280], length 38
20:50:23.638150 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [.], ack 467, win 7, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138314 ecr 797468369], length 0
20:50:23.638178 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [P.], seq 2415:3253, ack 467, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138314 ecr 797468369], length 838
20:50:23.638803 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 3253, win 991, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468401 ecr 1913138314], length 0
20:50:23.640496 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 467:491, ack 3253, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468403 ecr 1913138314], length 24
20:50:23.677060 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [P.], seq 3253:3277, ack 467, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138344 ecr 797468401], length 24
20:50:23.677097 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [F.], seq 3277, ack 491, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138344 ecr 797468403], length 0
20:50:23.678255 IP imx6ulevk.48158 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [F.], seq 491, ack 3278, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 797468441 ecr 1913138344], length 0
20:50:23.698249 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.48158: Flags [.], ack 492, win 7, options [nop,nop,TS val 1913138373 ecr 797468441], length 0
20:50:25.405702 IP imx6ulevk.33962 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 224
20:50:27.420792 IP imx6ulevk.50365 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 324
20:50:29.458380 IP imx6ulevk.53421 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 424
20:50:31.484379 IP imx6ulevk.54627 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 524
20:50:33.493183 IP imx6ulevk.44632 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 624
20:50:35.514921 IP imx6ulevk.51923 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 724
20:50:37.530994 IP imx6ulevk.35136 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 824
20:52:48.134664 IP imx6ulevk.55539 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 924
20:55:17.950327 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [S], seq 4239583687, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3206509289 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
20:55:18.008198 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [S.], seq 637640323, ack 4239583688, win 65160, options [mss 1390,sackOK,TS val 3032516153 ecr 3206509289,nop,wscale 13], length 0
20:55:18.008722 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 1, win 1004, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509347 ecr 3032516153], length 0
20:55:18.015955 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 1:349, ack 1, win 1004, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509355 ecr 3032516153], length 348
20:55:18.061317 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [.], ack 349, win 7, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516205 ecr 3206509355], length 0
20:55:18.061384 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [P.], seq 1:167, ack 349, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516205 ecr 3206509355], length 166
20:55:18.061443 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [.], seq 167:1545, ack 349, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516206 ecr 3206509355], length 1378
20:55:18.063104 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 167, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509401 ecr 3032516205], length 0
20:55:18.063727 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 1545, win 991, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509402 ecr 3032516206], length 0
20:55:18.086273 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 349:355, ack 1545, win 991, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509425 ecr 3032516206], length 6
20:55:18.094297 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [P.], seq 1545:2417, ack 349, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516238 ecr 3206509401], length 872
20:55:18.148852 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 2417, win 991, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509488 ecr 3032516238], length 0
20:55:18.154072 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [.], ack 355, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516299 ecr 3206509425], length 0
20:55:18.186713 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 355:429, ack 2417, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509526 ecr 3032516299], length 74
20:55:18.213013 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [.], ack 429, win 7, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516358 ecr 3206509526], length 0
20:55:18.213364 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 429:467, ack 2417, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509552 ecr 3032516358], length 38
20:55:18.243306 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [.], ack 467, win 7, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516387 ecr 3206509552], length 0
20:55:18.243374 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [P.], seq 2417:3255, ack 467, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516388 ecr 3206509552], length 838
20:55:18.244443 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [.], ack 3255, win 991, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509583 ecr 3032516388], length 0
20:55:18.249130 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [P.], seq 467:491, ack 3255, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509587 ecr 3032516388], length 24
20:55:18.273044 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [P.], seq 3255:3279, ack 467, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516418 ecr 3206509583], length 24
20:55:18.273079 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [F.], seq 3279, ack 491, win 8, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516418 ecr 3206509587], length 0
20:55:18.274239 IP imx6ulevk.49440 > time.cloudflare.com.ntske: Flags [F.], seq 491, ack 3280, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 3206509613 ecr 3032516418], length 0
20:55:18.302933 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntske > imx6ulevk.49440: Flags [.], ack 492, win 7, options [nop,nop,TS val 3032516448 ecr 3206509613], length 0
20:55:19.988396 IP imx6ulevk.40096 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 224
20:55:22.029780 IP imx6ulevk.46017 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 324
20:55:24.071392 IP imx6ulevk.41942 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 424
20:55:26.111070 IP imx6ulevk.47738 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 524
20:55:28.134146 IP imx6ulevk.39702 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 624
20:55:30.143596 IP imx6ulevk.43911 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 724
20:55:32.186263 IP imx6ulevk.58869 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 824
21:04:05.861057 IP imx6ulevk.54154 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 924

So I am seeing NTP messages go from my client device to time.cloudflare.com, but I am not seeing the NTP messages from the server.
As I mentioned before, if I nix the NTS I see the server messages:
chronyc> delete time.cloudflare.com
200 OK
chronyc> sources
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
chronyc> add server time.cloudflare.com 
200 OK
chronyc> sources -v

  .-- Source mode  '^' = server, '=' = peer, '#' = local clock.
 / .- Source state '*' = current best, '+' = combined, '-' = not combined,
| /             'x' = may be in error, '~' = too variable, '?' = unusable.
||                                                 .- xxxx [ yyyy ] +/- zzzz
||      Reachability register (octal) -.           |  xxxx = adjusted offset,
||      Log2(Polling interval) --.      |          |  yyyy = measured offset,
||                                \     |          |  zzzz = estimated error.
||                                 |    |           \
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^? time.cloudflare.com           3   6     1    19  -19922h[-19922h] +/-   96ms
chronyc> 

root@imx6ulevk:~# tcpdump -i eth0 host 162.159.200.123 or host 162.159.200.1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
21:18:14.010089 IP imx6ulevk.59358 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
21:18:14.177014 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntp > imx6ulevk.59358: NTPv4, Server, length 48
21:19:19.313682 IP imx6ulevk.52019 > time.cloudflare.com.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
21:19:19.476925 IP time.cloudflare.com.ntp > imx6ulevk.52019: NTPv4, Server, length 48

The modem is running some stock settings, and I have seen NTS work correctly on the same make/modem modem with a different carrier in a different region. So, I suspect this issue is specific to this carrier. Also, I can reproduce this issue when I connect to the modem using my laptop.
In my chrony.conf I have: nocerttimecheck 1. Also, this works on other networks so I don't think this is an issue with root CA certs.
I am unsure what to do to troubleshoot this issue further or if there are any other relevant settings on chrony I should attempt to adjust.

It's a networking issue. Your packet capture clearly shows that NTS-protected NTP packets are not getting back from the server. Some ISPs are known to block larger NTP packets as a mitigation for old amplification attacks exploiting the private monitoring/management protocol of ntpd (mode 6 and mode 7).
You can ask your ISP to reconsider this blocking. As NTS is being adopted, more customers will complain.
One thing you can try on your side is to get a newer version of chrony with enabled support for AES-SIV-GCM, which will make the NTP packets shorter and less likely to be blocked by the ISP. Cloudflare supports it on their servers.
